# Find an eigenvalue of $A ( − 5 A − 2 I ) + 4 I$ knowing that, 5 is an eigenvalue of A.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Matrix $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix ($n ≥ 100$) and one of its eigenvalues is 5.

> Find an eigenvalue of this matrix $A ( − 5 A − 2 I ) + 4 I$.

I presume $I$ is an identity matrix.

The matrix simplified is

$$A ( − 5 A − 2 I ) + 4 I= -5 A^2 -2 A I + 4 I$$

since $A * I = A$. Where do I go from here?

Comment: You will need the property $Ax=\lambda{x}$ here

Comment: Does that mean $A = λ$ if you divide that equation with $x$?

Comment: $A$ is a matrix, $\lambda$ is a number

Comment: @CocaKola31 I concur with Guy's answer. Quick and concise

Comment: @imranfat Good. So is $-58$ matrix's $A(5A+3I)−2I$ eigenvalue if $Ax=-2x$? I calculated it the same way Guy answered the original assignment.

Comment: @CocaKola31  ?I did not get $-58$. Did you get at some point $-10Ax-6x-2x$ at some point?

Comment: @imranfat I checked again I used $5$ as the eigenvalue accidentally. Now with $-2$, i got $12$. Is that right?

Comment: @CocaKola31 Yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x$ be an  eigenvector of A corresponding to the eigenvalue 5

Then $Ax= 5x$ we have ,

$$(-5 A^2 -2 A I + 4 I)x= -5 A^2x -2 A x + 4 x\\= -25Ax -10x+4x\\=-125x-10x+4x =-131x$$
Hence, -131 is an eigenvalue of $-5 A^2 -2 A I + 4 I$

Comment: Where does the middle part of that solution come from? $=−25Ax−1=0x+4x$? Specifically $-1$ and $0x$.

Comment: Sorry it is a typo. check now

Comment: Ah ok. So basically you just swap $A$s with one of it's eigenvalues and $I$s with x.

Comment: Of course since $Ax=5x$ and $Ix=x$

Answer (score 2):

Post-multiply with a the eigenvector, $v$, corresponding to the eigenvalue $5$ of $A$. Then 
$$-5A^2v-2Av+4Iv=-5A(5v)-2.(5v)+4v=-5^2(5v)-6v=-131v$$
So $-131$ is an eigenvalue of the given matrix.

In general if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $p(A)=a_0I+a_1A+a_2A^2+\cdots+a_nA^n$ is a polynomial in the matrix $A$, then $p(\lambda)=p(A)=a_0+a_1\lambda+a_2\lambda^2+\cdots+a_n\lambda^n$ is an eigenvalue of $p(A)$.

Comment: I answered 19 and apparently "Your answer is not necessarily the eigenvalue of the matrix". Then it gave me a new, but similar assignment. This time the $A$ eigenvalue in this assignment is $-2$ and the matrix is $A(5A-3I)−2I$. I have to solve that's eigenvalue.

Comment: Now that I look at your final output wasn't the answer $119$ instead of $19$?

Comment: sorry i miscalculated. I have edited my answer now. See it

Comment: Shouldn be -131 instead  of 19?

Comment: Ah ok. Well I'll try to solve the new assignment the way you did it. $A(5A+3I)−2I$ with $A$'s eigenvalue $-2$